# Django disqus startup

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, disqus

Well I guess that most of Django developers are aware of the fact that the default Django's comment system is deprecated and no longer supported, so now ive decided to go for a reliable system such as disqus to handle my website's commenting system but there are several obstacles I need to solve before being able to make it functional(using Django-disqus plugin):

(The scenario is that the user leaves a comment for an article published by another user, and consequently, the user receiving the comment should be able to see all of the comments left by users for his articles in his profile section as well as being able to moderate them, something like a social website)

first of all it asks for API_KEY and whatever guide ive read for obtaining one is no longer valid(it looks like that disqus has a little shift in their strategy regarding api keys)

another is the fact that the Django package repo description says that the plugin supports moderation but I cant find it anywhere

and lastly, I also need to find a way to either store the comments locally or use remote queries to filter out comments in each profile section properly, or maybe there is another way that slipped my mind?

if the disqus plugin is not suitable for this situation, a suggestion for another Django plugin for comments handling and moderation with a tutorial is also welcome.

BTW the python version is 3.4 and Django version is 1.8, (both stable)